# An exercise from 'Giaquinta,Modica,Mathematical Analysis,2'

Tags: calculus

Here is a exercise from **Giaquinta,Modica,Mathematical Analysis,2** It is a last exercise from chapter 2

Let $f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$.  show that for any $y \in \Bbb{R}$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$ the function $$(f(x)-y)^2+\frac{1}{n}x^2$$ has a minimum point $x_n$

For there is no continuous assumption on $f(x)$. So I consider the Dirichlet function

$$D(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \in \Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}\\1 & x \in \Bbb{Q}\end{cases} $$

and set $y=0$,$n=1$. then if $x\in \Bbb{Q}$, the expression $f^2(x)+x^2 \geq 1$. so any rational point is not a minimum. if $x\in \Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}$, $f^2(x)+x^2=x^2$, we can find a $x_n \in \Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}$ such that $x_n^2 \rightarrow 0$, but $x_n$ is irrational. so $f^2+x^2$ don't has a minimum point. I don't know what mistake I have made. could you help me? thanks very much.

Comment: Really, no assumption on $f$? If it is continuous, you can do it. Otherwise, you found a neat counter-example.

Comment: What is $x_n$? ${}{}$

Comment: yes,no assumption. and$x_n$ is a expectation minimum point in the exercise. and in my counter-example. $x_n$ is a irrational sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=0$, $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x\leq 0 \\ x & x > 0\end{cases}$. Then $f(x)^2+ \frac{1}{n} x^2$ has no minimum on $\mathbb{R}$, but $\inf_x ( f(x)^2+ \frac{1}{n} x^2 ) = 0$